# "A hot key was detected in step 'ReadMessageFromPubsubSubscription/PubsubUnboundedSource' " warning occurs in streaming dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a dataflow pipeline that read json message from `Pub/Sub` subscription, transform json message to tableRows and Mutations separately and finally write into BigQuery and Spanner after some validations.

But we get `"A hot key was detected in step'ReadMessageFromPubsubSubscription/PubsubUnboundedSource' "` warning inside PubsubIO step. There is performance deterioration when the warning occurs.

The first step of the pipeline is `PubsubIO.readStrings` and the following step are all ParDo transform. There are no GroupBy or Combine. I'm confused why there is `"hotkey"` happening. What key is it that used inside PubsubIO?

Here is part of the code.

```
PCollection<List<Entry>> p1 = p
                .apply("ReadMessageFromPubsubSubscription", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(opt.getPubsubSubscriptionPath()))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractorEntryFromMessage()));

        //the line that write into BigQuery
        p1
                .apply("ConvertTableRow",ParDo.of(new TransformToTableRow()))
                .apply("WriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                        .to(opt.getOutputBQPath())
                        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                        .withCustomGcsTempLocation(opt.getCustomGcsTempLocation());


        //the line that write into Spanner       
        p1
                .apply("Validation1", ParDo.of(new Validation1()))
                .apply("Validation2", ParDo.of(new Validation2()))
                .apply("Validation3", ParDo.of(new Validation3()))
                .apply("WriteToSpanner", ParDo.of(new WriteToSpanner()));
        p.run();
```

Comment: This usually means that the DataflowRunner detected a key with a large number of values that can negatively affect performance. See here for more details and possible steps to mitigate this: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#hot-key-detected

Answer (score 0):

I believe Pub/Sub reading cannot be a step for a hot key detection, it doesn't make sense to see Hot keys in it.
This is a false positive, you can just ignore it.